# Embed LaTeX equations in website

Tags: web-apps, html, latex

I need a HTML LaTeX equation editor that creates graphical equations in the form of image (.png, .jpg, etc.) and produces code for directly embedding equations into HTML websites.

[Codecogs](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php&ei=Zcv_UvjsHofBrAedygE&usg=AFQjCNGYhRExO-ZuSCaerqQG9rE0zV1IrQ&sig2=987uTqr3RsOaLaF9IQBn6Q&bvm=bv.61535280,d.bmk) used to be my choice for this, but since past few days, it's service has been disrupted and I need an alternate.

PS: I know I can do this with `MathJAX/JSMath`, but I need an image output only.

Comment: Doesn't codecogs use Mathjax?

Comment: @Huey I have no clue. But most probably, yes.

Comment: And even if it does, the final output is an image.

Comment: Google has a [very handy API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/formulas) for this, but unfortunately it is deprecated and not guaranteed to be working after April 20, 2015.

Comment: Does it have to be WYSIWYG, or are you going to type the LaTeX? Does it have to be a webapp, or can you use a local LaTeX installation? How do you plan on managing the source and the image (e.g. version control, CMS)?

Comment: I need exactly what codecogs does. It basically uses a MathJAX/JSMath plugin to render text into latex and then creates an image out of it which can be embedded in an html page. While doing so is very trivial, and can be done in a local latex installation, I need something that is accessible on the go, no matter which system I'm working on, whether LaTeX compiler is installed on not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need an image output only, the [Daum Equation Editor](http://s1.daumcdn.net/editor/fp/service_nc/pencil/Pencil_chromestore.html) may be worth a try. It's a browser-based WYSIWYG LaTeX editor that allows you to save LaTeX equations as *.png* images.

Here's a sample screenshot of the editor:

[image]

And here's a sample *.png* image saved by it:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations. This is not a good answer for our site, please review [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) meta post on how to write good answers.

Comment: @aman207 Thank you for pointing this out. I've now tried to improve the answer as per the meta post.

Comment: Why downvotes now that OP's improved his answer? Would be nice if people explained their reasoning. .-.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure there are no delays, I recommend you to put the workload of rendering to the client. Libraries such as [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org)/[jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) allow you to render the Latex code directly in the visitor's browser. This has the nice side effect that this content is accessible for screen readers that do not support to display pictures.

Comment: I agree that MathJAX/JSMath libraries would do my job. But these are heavy dependencies, LaTeX text just forms 0.001% of my website. Hence, I'd like to stick to the outsourcing option.

Comment: If it is that little, why not just create static images manually from some LaTeX software whenever it is needed?

Comment: To those downvoting: I answered before the edit specified that MathJax/jsMath wasn't an option, I guess the edit was a reaction to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) will plot simple LaTex equations into images and graphs for you. I do not know how it handles more complex stuff.